# RestKit: how to handle case where children are delivered in a different JSON payload?

Tags: ios, restkit

I am trying to connect to an API that only embeds IDs for children, not the objects themselves.
For instance:

```
{
  "post": {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "New post",
        "body": "A body!",
        "comment_ids": [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  }
}
```

To get `post.comments`, you need to query the API again.

I looked at this RestKit's unit test to create the connections:
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/Tests/Logic/ObjectMapping/RKObjectManagerTest.m#L1453-L1484

and I think it is working. But there is one thing I don't understand:

if somewhere in the code I need to access a comment:

```
pots.comments.anyObject
```

do I have to manually trigger the http get, or does RestKit lazy load automatically? It looks like it needs to be done manually, but I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestKit will not lazy load automatically. You would usually trigger the download when the post details are required (like when the detail view was shown in a master-detail setup).

You will probably need a request descriptor so that when you POST the post RestKit will send the comment ids. Then the response would be a post object (or at least a container) and a list of comments.